How to calculate the aircraft ground run distance?
I am stumped with calculating the ground run length of an aircraft. I have access to formulas etc which would usually be used. However, I feel like I'm lacking the data needed to answer these questions.
I am not given the data for either rotational or lift off velocity. And I'm aware these can be estimated using stall velocity, however I am also not given any lift coefficient. Furthermore, we are not told the thrust, just the engine power which again I feel is useless without the velocity values.
The only information given about the lift coefficients, is that the flaps cause a 30% increase.
If I'm missing something obvious I apologise. However, I've been stumped for a while.
Thanks in advance.

https://aviation.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question. "Ground run length", I suspect, is not a commonly used term. Do you mean "take-off distance"? (I'm not an aviation engineer.)

We lack the data you need to supply - formulae, attempts at solutions etc

The question needs some details and specifics about the problem. Thanks. This could be a good question to check the general knowledge of a candidate engineer.
Otherwise, if you know the aircraft is smaller than a 747, a ground run length of 10.000ft would be sufficient. :)

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for this question.

I'm pretty sure these things are determined emperically via testing the aircraft.

A similar question was answered on the aviation stack about two years ago regarding K.9793 and P.7280, prototype Spitfire aircraft.  See the public service announcement in the answer, a word from our sponsor. Your question on the aviation stack has been seen by me, and an answer is being prepared.  An example electric aircraft may be used in that answer or any specific aircraft such as the one you have been given.  Data regarding the subject aircraft of your question would be helpful.
